# Custom connectors for integrating SpeechRecognition & RASA

Tags: integration, speech-recognition, rasa

What are the custom connectors to be used when we need to SpeechRecognition python object & RASA (cmd)

Comment: Could you add some clarification? What speech recognition service are you trying to use?

Comment: {{import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Speak Anything: ')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said:{}'.format(text))
    except:
        print('Sorry could not recognize what you said')}}     Above code should provide the "text" for questions/ queries in RASA Chatbot. Needed help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the STT (Speech to text) and TTS(text to speech) as well in rasa - which will build voice assistant.

To implement it , refer official link  where you can find some detailed examples on the Rasa blog:

https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-mozilla-tools/

https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-mobile-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-aimybox/

If you don't mind using something closed source, integrating the Google Speech API is also an option.